# I am looking to create a shortcut to put the display to sleep

Tags: display, keyboard-shortcuts, suspend

When I'm running a task in Elementary that takes a prolonged time, I'd like to switch off the display until an event like the mouse moving or keystroke "wakes" it back up again.

On MacOS and Windows I can do this using a system call but Elementary Linux, no luck so far...

I've tried **xset dpms force off** but the screen "wakes" back up after a short time.

Suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.

-TechScott.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:`xset -display :0.0 dpms force off`

Comment: additionally you can turn it off by removing the display output from like ' xrandr : xrandr --output dp-1 --off' but you'll have to run an "on" command afterwards as it won't turn on automatically

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand. Have a nice day!